Is There any way to view docx file in flutter app
im about to view pdf,jpeg,mp4 and docx file in flutter i have done all the file format except docx
is there any package available with playstore support
and i have tried the package called flutter_file_view.
this is output i had when run on real device
To reiterate a problem 1.need a package with playstore support 2.if no solution is there any other way to do this like (buying lisence ... etc )
the below thing is the error section :
D/com.file.view.FlutterFileViewPlugin(31596): FlutterFileView: TBS - Ready to initialize.
D/com.file.view.FlutterFileViewPlugin(31596): FlutterFileView: TBS - Start the initialization.
D/com.file.view.FlutterFileViewPlugin(31596): FlutterFileView: TBS - Download completed - 127 - FAIL
D/com.file.view.FlutterFileViewPlugin(31596): FlutterFileView: TBS - Current Status - DOWNLOAD_OUT_OF_ONE

You can use webview_flutter plugin to load a web page that displays the DOCX file using an online viewer.

It works   Thank you.
controller = WebViewController()
..setNavigationDelegate(NavigationDelegate(
onPageStarted: (url) {
setState(() {
loadingPercentage = 0;
});
},
onProgress: (progress) {
setState(() {
loadingPercentage = progress;
});
},
onPageFinished: (url) {
setState(() {
loadingPercentage = 100;
});
},
))
..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=Your Url}'));

Do you want the file to be opened inside your app or with an external tool on the phone?
If you want to open it with an external program, for instance, Google Docs, or whatever program the user has selected to use to open .docx files, then you can use this package https://pub.dev/packages/open_filex.

thanks for the quick reply i already did. downloading and opening the file using open file x but all i need is like preview type of view ( inside my app i need to view )

When you use flutter_file_view to view your file, does your widget that represents the view page have a scaffold? For the link you provided it looks like it has no scaffold.

yes i forget to put scaffold on that image provided will update the image
but the error still occurs

if i tap that buttoni get this error
D/com.file.view.FlutterFileViewPlugin(31596): FlutterFileView: TBS - Start the initialization. D/com.file.view.FlutterFileViewPlugin(31596): FlutterFileView: TBS - Download completed - 127 - FAIL D/com.file.view.FlutterFileViewPlugin(31596): FlutterFileView: TBS - Current Status - DOWNLOAD_OUT_OF_ONE

Reading this issue (https://github.com/LiWenHui96/flutter_file_view/issues/26), I understand they will stop supporting this feature soon on Android. So better don't use this one.

is there any alternate way to view docx file...?

Not any I am aware of. You could try some from pub.dev
